# WSO2 service generate wsdl is empty

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, wso2, wsh

I've installed wso2 on my server and I've created some webservice and clients with given WSDL documents. But now I have to create a WSDL from my own created service. But when I call my service url with "?wsdl", I get an empty document.. Does somebody know what I am doing wrong?
The same happens when I do it with a sample of the wsdl_generation directory rpc_service.php?wsdl.

Please help me.

Comment: it is hard to say, as I don't understand your question. Do you have wso2 ESB or what? What you mean for "create a WSDL": you wrote it manually, or just copied the address of a generated one? If you created it manually there is change you did an error there. What are you doing with WSO2 because it looks like it doesn't anything in your case. Please Edit your question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is your case, but some browsers like Safari does not show XML code. Try to do something like "View Page Source" if it does not show anything tell me..

Comment: No that is not the case, I always check the page source... but it is empty :(